# Parametrize URL in Azure Data Factory Web activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can we parametrize the URL in the web activity? I understand that you can create a http linked service, but how to use if from a web activity? Any other ways except Linked Services?

Parametrizing the ARM template is not an option because it will be auto-generated from the Data Factory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a parameter within pipeline and then pass to URL in web activity.

For example:

1.create a parameter within pipeline

[image]

2.pass to your URL in web activity

[image]